# How to load api data from nodejs server in the background an append them to datatable

Tags: html, node.js, json, fetch, ejs

My nodejs api looks like

```js
router.get("/inventory", function(req, res, next) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        db.getFullInventory().then(function(result) {
            resolve((res.send(result)).json());
        }).catch(
            function(err) {
                reject(res.send(err));
            }
        )
    })
});
// this is very slow
router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
    db.getFullInventory().then(function(result) {
        if (req.session.user) { res.render("dashboard", { items: result }); } else { res.redirect('/') }
    }).catch(
        function(err) {
            res.send(err);

        }
    )
});
```

I want to load an ejs page and slowly keep adding my data to `DataTable`
I was trying to use fetch but it seemed to get null even though when I simply browse to that route I can see all my data.
Any ways I can achieve this?

Comment: Maybe at first render, dont get the full inventory, and get only first `n` items. After the render, the page can ask for more items using Ajax.

Comment: I was thinking about using thw fetch function, to get data from the /inventory url. I tried using it got cors policy error, so I added no cors and then I just don't get any data. I am pretty sure my implementation is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

use app.use(cors())
That should sort the issues.